# Is there any modern language that is currently shifting from one stage to the next in Jespersen's cycle?

Tags: linguistic-typology, list-of-languages, language-change, negation

Modern French seems to be going through the next stage in [Jespersen's cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jespersen%27s_Cycle), from `Neg-V-Neg` to `V-Neg`; i.e. `Ce n'est pas toi` to `C'est pas toi`.

What else is shifting from one to the next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welsh is around the same point as French, or maybe slightly further. Literary Welsh retains the original negative particle.

> Ni chafodd ef ddim syndod

> Not received he not surprise

but everyday Welsh drops it

> Chafodd e ddim syndod

Sometimes the negative particle partly survives, either as the *-d* of the prevocal variant:

> Nid wyf i ddim yn mynd -> Dwy ddim yn mynd

> Not am I not in going

or in mutation of the following consonant: in the example above, compare *Cafodd e syndod* "He received a surprise" without aspiration of the /c/.